# Sort Label values on an axis in Bar Chart

Tags: sorting, spotfire

I'm trying to create a Bar chart for a Survey Question. The Survey Question has the possible options

- Strongly Agree
- Agree
- Neither Agree nor Disagree
- Disagree
- Strongly Disagree
- N/A

I would want the same order of the labels on the Scale as well. The Sort properties available in Visualization properties are:

Sort by Value, Sort bar segments by value, Reverse bar segment order

Can anyone please help me over here by lending a hand?

Comment: Please write some code, let us know what you have got already, where you are stuck, what languages you are using etc.

Comment: @DarkMukke this is a valid question in the context of Spotfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spotfire you can't set up custom sort in visualization, need to do it for the column itself, and all visualizations referring to that column will follow it.

Go to:

- edit
- column properties
- select the column you want to sort
- select "sort order" tab
- select "custom sort order"
- click "configure"

official help: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/data/data_details_on_custom_sort_order.htm